# Firebase SignIn error only in android release mode

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, release, unhandled-exception

I have phone sign in with Firebase in my flutter app and it all works perfectly in debug mode both iOS and Android but when **in release mode it throws an error** **only on Android device (physical). iOS still works perfect in release mode.**

```
[+9626 ms] E/flutter (21573): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
[        ] E/flutter (21573): #0      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber.<anonymous closure> (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:655)
[        ] E/flutter (21573): #1      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1593)
[        ] E/flutter (21573): #2      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339)
[        ] E/flutter (21573): #3      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:515)
[        ] E/flutter (21573): #4      _PendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:620)
[        ] E/flutter (21573): #5      _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591)
[        ] E/flutter (21573): #6      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40)
[        ] E/flutter (21573): #7      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49)
[        ] E/flutter (21573):
```

This is my function

```
 Future verifyPhoneNumber() async {
    
      try {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: _telNumberController.text,
          verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
            print('COMPLETED');
          
          },
          verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
            print('FAILED');
          },
          codeSent: (
            String verificationId,
            int? resendToken,
          ) {
            print('CODE SENT');
          },
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
        );
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
```

Its passing the phone number correctly but even not reaching any `print` - neither for `verificationCompleted` nor `verificationFailed`

any ideas why can I get this behavior?

**UPD:** I found out that my release SHA1 and SHA256 were different from the debug ones so I added them to Firebase, downloaded new google-services.json file, run flutter clean but.. the problem persists. I believe it has something to do with re-Captcha that the app can't perform in release mode.

**UPD2** I also added SHA keys from Google Play Store. So now I have debug, release and Google Play SHA1 and SHA256. But still have the same error and still it works perfect in debug but not in release

**UPD3**
found that it happens when I change in build.gradle
from

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
```

to

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.release
```

So something is wrong with the release signinConfig
I do

1. Create an upload keystore
   with this command
   ~keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload~
2. Create key.properties in android folder

```
    storePassword=***
    keyPassword=***
    keyAlias=upload
    storeFile=/Users/amarchuk/upload-keystore.jks~
```

3. Configure signing in gradle
   this code before the android block

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }
```

4. And inside the android block

```
signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: have to check where you're getting null instead of a string.

Comment: make sure you are testing it on real device.

Comment: you need to add fingerprint of google play console app id

Comment: @TasnuvaTavasumoshin yes I mentioned that in the post. I have 3 SHA1 fingerprints

Comment: @Rahul of course, it just not possible to run --release on emulator

Comment: @ManishDayma as I mentioned - the error comes from signingConfig signingConfigs.release that is in build.gradle. How to get log/print inside build.gradle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally! After a week of suffering I found where its coming from
In your Google Could Console https://console.cloud.google.com/ - Credentials - API Keys - you have your Android Key.
I had it restricted for Android Apps as it should be but there you have to add your SHA1 key and I had only my debug SHA1 key but not the release key.
Adding release key solved the issues. Hope it will be helpful for other users
[image: Android key settings in Google Cloud Console]

Comment: Thank you!! I have been digging for a week until I found your solution! super glad :)